# Indirect modification of overloaded property Model has no effect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is a frequently asked question here, but it's the first time I'm encountering this problem and none of the other questions are exactly like mine.

As far as I'm concerned I'm copying [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates) exactly, but I'm getting this error. I assume it's to do with the sub-relationships between models.

```
    $attendance = AttendingActor::findOrFail($currentAttendance);
    $attendance->character->school_class_id = $classId;
    $attendance->character->save();
```

Why am I *sometimes* getting the following error?

> Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Attendance::$character has no effect

And why if I change it to the following, do I get an error 100% of the time?

```
    $attendance = AttendingActor::findOrFail($currentAttendance);
    $attendance->character->schoolClass->id = $classId;
    $attendance->character->save();
```

The models `AttendingActor` and `Character` have a 1:1 relationship, so why is it problematic updating them in this way?

Comment: This is likely a side effect of Laravel's magic get and set logic. I see this happen when (in your example) `$attendance->character` is `null`, and you try to set a property of it (`$attendance->character->school_class_id = whatever`). You say `AttendingActor` and `Character` have a one-to-one, but is that optional? A simple check around it, like `if($attendance->character){ ... }` would handle this. Or, `AttendingActor::has(['character'])->findOrFail(...);`; that'll fail if the `character` relationship is `null`.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks. It's weird because there should never be a case where it's `null`, but maybe it a bug elsewhere with the code.

Comment: No problem! I see this happen a lot too if the models are using  `SoftDeletes`; the related ids are intact, but the actual record is "deleted" and not retrieved by the query. The method `->withTrashed()` on the relationship, or in a `->with()`/`->whereHas()` clause handles that so `$model->relationship` isn't `null`, but that's an edge case I suppose. Might be something else completely.

Comment: @TimLewis Interesting! We are using `SoftDeletes` on those models, actually.

Comment: Then that's possibly it. If the model (parent or related) is using `use SoftDeletes;` all queries performed on it will automatically look for `WHERE NULL deleted_at`. Check the database record you expect to be returned for `$attendance->character` and see if it has been deleted.